# How to convert elements of an Observable array into a tuples

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, observable

I retrieve data from firestore that i want to use for an echarts graph.
In end up with `seagulls: Observable<SeagullId[]>;`

```
export interface Seagull { date: string; amount: number; name: string; }
export interface SeagullId extends Seagull { id: string; }

export class ZonesComponent implements OnInit {

  private seagullCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Seagull>;
  seagulls: Observable<SeagullId[]>;

  constructor(private readonly afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.seagullCollection = afs.collection<Seagull>('mowe');
    // .snapshotChanges() returns a DocumentChangeAction[], which contains
    // a lot of information about "what happened" with each change. If you want to
    // get the data and the id use the map operator.
    this.seagulls = this.seagullCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Seagull;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
  }
```

Now i need to transfrom each elem of `seagulls: Observable<SeagullId[]>` to`[date, value, name]`.
Hard coded example:

```
series: [
      {
          type: 'themeRiver',
          emphasis: {
              itemStyle: {
                  shadowBlur: 20,
                  shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
              }
          },
          data: [['2015/11/08',10,'Lachmöwe'],['2015/11/09',15,'Lachmöwe'],['2015/11/10',35,'Lachmöwe'],
          ['2015/11/11',38,'Lachmöwe'],['2015/11/12',22,'Lachmöwe'],['2015/11/13',16,'Lachmöwe']..
```

My approach is the following:

```
series: [
      {
        type: 'themeRiver',
        emphasis: {
          itemStyle: {
            shadowBlur: 20,
            shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
          }
        },
        data: this.seagulls
        .pipe(map(data => {
          data.map(elem => {
            return [elem.date, elem.amount, elem.name]
          })
        }))
      }
    ]
```

But the data type is not mapping correctly... how can i use `seagulls: Observable<SeagullId[]>` as my data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `seagulls: Observable<SeagullId[]>`. Observables are lazy so if you don't subscribe to them you will not receive any value back.

That brings another issue, Observables are asynchronous. That is they will return value in a future time. So you will need to subscribe, get a value and only now do the mapping

```typescript
  private seagullCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Seagull>;
  seagulls: Observable<SeagullId[]>;
  seagullsMapped: any;

  constructor(private readonly afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.seagullCollection = afs.collection<Seagull>('mowe');
    // .snapshotChanges() returns a DocumentChangeAction[], which contains
    // a lot of information about "what happened" with each change. If you want to
    // get the data and the id use the map operator.
    this.seagulls = this.seagullCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Seagull;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
    this.seagulls.subscribe({
      next: (seagulls) => {
        this.seagullsMapped = {
        series: [
          {
            type: 'themeRiver',
            emphasis: {
              itemStyle: {
                shadowBlur: 20,
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
              }
           },
           data: seagulls.map(elem => {
              return [elem.date, elem.amount, elem.name]
           })
        
          }
        ]
       }
      }
    })
  }
```